# Formik: How to reset form after confirming on dialog

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I want to reset form after submitting

I used resetForm() on child component, it actually worked, but when click on the button on child Component, resetForm works

```
  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [showDialog, setShowDialog] = useState(false);
  const [sendParams, setSendParams] = useState<sendParams>();
  const handleSubmit = (values: FormValues) => {
    setShowDialog(true);
    setSendParams(values);
  };

  const handleConfirm = () => {
    setSubmitting(true);
  // send to API
    sendParams && dispatch(sendRequest(sendParams));
  };

  return (
  // child component which has forms and button to show confirmation dialog
      <Page message='' submitting={submitting} onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
  // when button on child component is clicked, dialog appears
  // Click the button to submit on dialog 
      <Dialog
        show={showDialog}
        submitting={submitting}
        onConfirm={handleConfirm}
      />
  )
```

I tried to use `resetForm` like this

```
  const [handleResetForm, setHandleResetForm] = useState<() => void>();
  const handleSubmit = (values: FormValues, resetForm: () => void) => {
    setShowDialog(true);
    setSendParams(values);
    setHandleResetForm(resetForm);
  };
```

Sorry for the mess,
any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you post `sendRequest` as well?

Comment: Can you show how you tried to implement `resetForm`? It should do what you want, and I don't quite understand "resets when the dialog is shown"

Comment: @hotcakedev yes

Comment: @Jayce444 i'll add on below about resetForm, thanks! I meant when click on the button on child Component, resetForm works

Comment: When I tried your approach I got *"Warning: Cannot update a component (`Formik`) while rendering a different component (`MyComponent`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `MyComponent`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render"* Was that happening to you?

Comment: @LindaPaiste I haven't got any warnings, resetForm worked on wrong timing.

Answer (score 0):

Add resetForm on submit and call it.

```
const checkLogin = (values, resetForm) => {
resetForm.resetForm()
}
```

This should resolve your issue.